# How to only use one loop per multiple function executions in a redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

So, I have a Redux-action that gets called multiple times throughout my application, essentially what I need is for every time it calls the action it just resets a setInterval for 10 second with the new data that is passed in the action.

```
export function fetchInterviewer(lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone) {
    setInterval(()=>{
        fetchInterviewerLoop(lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone);
    },10000)
}

export function fetchInterviewerLoop(lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone){
    Store.dispatch(interviewerIsLoading(callId));

    let p = phone && SystemService.decodePhone(phone);

    return {
        type: CALL_FETCH_INTERVIEWER,
        payload: HttpService.get(`${lastInterviewerId}/interview/${interviewId}/interviewer?phone=${p}`)
    }
}
```

The problem is that every time the fetchInterviewer is called in the application, it doesn't just restart the function, it just creates a new separate looping instance, so I could call the action 10 times and then I'll have 10 different loops.

I've tried multiple different things and I feel like the answer is probably something so small and stupid.

Comment: I'd like to add that, I quickly just typed this code up to reflect an example of the problem I'm trying to solve. It is not actual code.

Comment: You might be looking for https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp to get rid of formerly launched interval.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo To stop the interval yes, but it would need to do so every time the action is called while also starting a new one with the new action data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to stop the interval you can use an object that references the loop params:

```
let paramsRef;
let interval;
export function fetchInterviewer(lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone) {
    paramsRef =  {lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone}
    if(!interval){
        interval = setInterval(()=>{
            const {lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone} = paramsRef
            fetchInterviewerLoop(lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone);
        },10000)
    }
}

export function fetchInterviewerLoop(lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone){
    Store.dispatch(interviewerIsLoading(callId));

    let p = phone && SystemService.decodePhone(phone);

    return {
        type: CALL_FETCH_INTERVIEWER,
        payload: HttpService.get(`${lastInterviewerId}/interview/${interviewId}/interviewer?phone=${p}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution makes sense too me but I always get this error. "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Comment: I guees payload of `fetchInterviewerLoop` is a Promise, therefore, the action is not a plain object. You should try to use `redux-thunk`, `redux-saga`, `redux-promise` or any other middleware for async actions

Answer (score 1):

Stop the current interval before setting another one:

```
let currentInterval = null;

export function fetchInterviewer(lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone) {
  clearInterval(currentInterval);

  currentInterval = setInterval(()=>{
    fetchInterviewerLoop(lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone);
  },10000)
}

export function fetchInterviewerLoop(lastInterviewerId, interviewId, phone){
  Store.dispatch(interviewerIsLoading(callId));

  let p = phone && SystemService.decodePhone(phone);

  return {
    type: CALL_FETCH_INTERVIEWER,
    payload: 
    HttpService.get(`${lastInterviewerId}/interview/${interviewId}/interviewer?phone=${p}`)
  }
}
```